# Unable to scrape a website with requests_html

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am trying to make a script that tracks parcels from different couriers, but the issue is, requests_html doesn't seem to work on their javascript. [This][1] is a link I'd like to scrape information out of. Opening up the html, I can see this  javascript function:

```
        function stopLoading(error) {//loading hide

        $('#progress').css('display', 'none');
        if (!error) {
            $('#main-content').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('#divError').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divError p').text(error);
        }
    }
```

I can guess that if there's no error(?) **main-content** becomes visible and **divError** stays in display none. But whenever I run my script the results range from an error in loading to both **divError** and **main-content** being in *display=none;*

This is my code

```
import bs4
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://wkfsrv.acscourier.net/apps/track-shipment/?id=4716811960')

r.html.render()
page=r.html.raw_html
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.decode('utf-8','ignore'),features="html.parser")
```

I've tried selenium but it's too heavy, sending the GET requests myself, but I'm not good enough to make it work, passing a Javascript argument in render() but it can't bring back stuff that's not there. Im beginning to think its an issue of the webpage itself.  Any help(even a confirmation of my conclusion above) would be helpful.
[1]: https://wkfsrv.acscourier.net/apps/track-shipment/?id=4718427210&token_hash=track-4718427210

Comment: The page you have placed does not load.
It has taken too long to respond.
It is very likely that the problem is the loading of the page. try to limit the number of records if you can. It is possible that you have a timeout by the script if the page takes a long time

Comment: Yes, I did find that the page experiences some issues once in a while. My other options are (https://www.acscourier.net/el/track-and-trace) and this iframe I made just to clear out some stuff (http://users.ntua.gr/nm18076/tracker.html). But I am not sure on how to provide the tracking code and scrape the data I need.